# C and C++ namespace

Tags: c++

I'm working on an old project where the bulk of it is written in C with some C++ added.  I am adding a new C++ class which references an enumerated type "ServiceType", this is defined in this block:

```
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        extern "C" {
            namespace ldv {
    #endif
    typedef enum {
        ACKD            = 0,
        UNACKD_RPT      = 1,
        UNACKD          = 2,
        REQUEST         = 3
    } ServiceType;
```

I am including the header that this code is defined in, but when I try to use the type as a parameter to a method I get:

```
    167 error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'ServiceType'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Error from C or C++ ?

Comment: `namespace` inside `extern "C"` ?

Comment: Godbolt is happy with the namespace as part of the type: https://godbolt.org/g/JzkT6k

Comment: @Jarod42, this is from an header called OpenLDVdefinitions.h which is part of echelon's OpenLDV development kit.

Comment: Please show the code that causes the error message. What kind of file (C/C++) contains the code? Is the header file #included here?

Comment: @harper, I have already...the only bit not showing is the method prototype in a C++ class which uses type as parameter.

Comment: @StephenNewell, thank you, thats sorted the problem.

Comment: you have to individually pull them into a namespace but it won't remove them from the global namespace